# How override Material UI Popover CSS classes in Select component in React

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, emotion

I am using [Material UI Select component](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/) inside my React project.

I am trying to override the CSS class `.MuiPaper-root` and or `.MuiMenu-list`.

My Select component:

```
<Select
  value={selectValue}
  disableUnderline
  onChange={handleChange}
  css={styles.select}
>
  {cities?.map((city) => {

    return (
      <MenuItem
        key={city.value}
        value={city.value}
        css={styles.selectItem}
      >
        {city.label}
      </MenuItem>
    );
  })}
</Select>
```

Below isn't working?

```
export default ({ theme }: StylesProps) => ({
 select: css`
   .MuiPaper-root {
      background-color: red;
    }
 `,
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/), there are several ways that we can modify styles in MUI. In order to change `MuiPaper`, we can take advantage of `createMuiTheme` and create a theme as below to override `MuiPaper`:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiPaper: {
      root: {
        color: "white"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Then, we need to pass it as a theme prop to the `ThemeProvider` component:

```
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          //***Other part of your code***//
      </ThemeProvider>
```

when it comes to changing MenuProps in the Select component, we can use a property called `MenuProps` in the `Select` component([description in doc](https://material-ui.com/api/select/))

First, I created a list style in `useStyles`:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
//other classes//
  list: {
    backgroundColor: "blue"
  }
}));
```

and then passed it as a `MenuProp` property to the select component:

```
          <Select
            labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
            id="demo-simple-select"
            value={age}
            onChange={handleChange}
            MenuProps={{ classes: { list: classes.list } }}
          >
                 //***other part of your code***//
          </Select>
```

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-0vrql?file=/demo.js) example that I've created for this example. In the `Muipaper` modification, I changed the color of the text to white. And in the `MenuProps` changed the background color to blue.

Comment: First import the `makeStyles` and then declare `const useStyles = makeStyles` outside the component. does it answer your question?

Comment: Just updated the answer. Let me know if it is clear now

Comment: I need to override `.MuiPaper-root`. In your example `root: classes.root` refers to the root of the Select component right? Because it's not working yet..

Comment: Your code example does not include `Paper` component. where is it coming from? and it is related to which one? can you share sample of your code in the sandbox?

Comment: Look on https://material-ui.com/components/selects/ when you open the select box (popup), a `div` is rendered with some classes like `MuiPaper-root`. I have to get rit of the white background...

Comment: Updated the answer completely. This answer should totally work for you. Pls let me know if it addressed all part of your question

Comment: Thanks I definitely accept your answer. I have my styles in a separate file (see question). How do I add them there instead of in my component file?

Comment: If you want to override MUI styles you need include your styles in the component.  Can you mark this answer the correct answer of your question? As you said it is the correct answer.